# Why is the initial size of UIScrollView still 320 on iPad?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

We have a xib that was currently designed for the iPhone.  We are porting the app to iPad.

We are using the paged portion of UIScrollView.  We have autoresizing masks set for width and height.  On the initial load for iPad the frame width is 320, which of course makes the UI look bad.

What's odd to us is that if you rotate the device, it "picks" up the new size based on the iPad screen width.  It is then correct from that point forward.

Do we need to initialize the frame width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the box that said "Targeted for iPad" when you create the XIB?
[image: Tageted for XIB checkbox]

If not, you have to manually edit the Xib (or recreate it again)

You need two different XIBs for the same controller. Instantiate them like this.

```
MyScrollViewController *controller;
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    // iphone related code
    controller = [[MyScrollViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyScrollViewController"
                                                                                          bundle:nil];
}   
else 
{
    // ipad related code
    controller = [[MyScrollViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyScrollViewController_iPad"
                                                                                          bundle:nil];
}   
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
[controller release];
```

Comment: So if I do that then will that break the iPhone layout?

Comment: You need two different XIBs - one for iPhone and one for iPad. When you create them, you init different XIBs for the same controller.